# How to find corner points , counts the shapes with hole and which given type python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I hope all are doing well.
I have the input image as shown below
I want to:

1. count the corner points in the image of a given color
2. count the shapes with hole in the image.
3. count the number of the shapes in the image of a given type (like
   triangles, circles, rectangles, etc.)

I have tried the following code for counting the corner points but it also counts the inner point of the shape.

How can I process from this point?

#### My code

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('/content/shapes.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,5,3,0.04)
ret, dst = cv2.threshold(dst,0.1*dst.max(),255,0)
dst = np.uint8(dst)
ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids),(5,5),(-1,-1),criteria)
for i in range(1, len(corners)):
    print(corners[i])
img[dst>0.1*dst.max()]=[255,0,255]
plt.imshow(img)
```

#### Input

[image: Input Image]

#### Output

[image: Output image]

Comment: I don't see why corner detectors would help here at all. -- why don't you work with contours and `approxPolyDP` instead? that's been written about plenty of times. distinguishing filled shaped from outlined shaped is "just" an extension of that. findContours can return the hierarchy of contours.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz How can I do that? basically i don't have any idea about that